# DataFormatString for currency is not working for danish culture

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have used `Dataformatstring = {0:c}` for currency,it's working fine for all currencies except some currencies like danish (DKK).

I want 123.45,00 DKK instead of 123,45.00.

Answer (score 2):

Are you setting the `CultureInfo`? The following works:

```
var amount = 12345.00;
var currency = amount.ToString("c", new CultureInfo("da-DK"));
Console.WriteLine(currency);
```

**Result:**

> kr. 12.345,00

Comment: I know this but i want to use this for my telerik html chart bar, for that i have to do this client side and i tried dataformatstring {0:c} and culture info "da-DK",but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This works, too:

```
var danishCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("da-DK");
var currency = string.Format(danishCulture, "{0:C}", 123.45);
```

Results in: `kr. 123,45`

Comment: it does not. For me at least, it results in "DKK123.45"